# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost : click timed out after 90 seconds

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting following error while executing the automation script on TFS Error,

Error message:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:59508/session/b655773d161676bad7ab56591cce3cf2/element/1560281f-e8b2-4bd7-a6c7-7eba3a94adc9/click timed out after 90 seconds.
----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
```

Stack trace:

```
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()
at QuotOMatic.Test.UI.Pages.Login.LogIn() in D:\B\2\2\s\QuotOMatic.Test.UI\Pages\Login.cs:line 117
at QuotOMatic.Test.UI.Tests.TC418369_Broker_Authentication_SmokeTest._Login() in D:\B\2\2\s\QuotOMatic.Test.UI\Tests\TC418369_Broker_Authentication_SmokeTest.cs:line 29
--WebException
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
```

I did the following work around to resolve this :

1. Used 'Submit' instead of 'Click'
2. Created process to identify open chrome instances on server and closed (Kill PID's) them
3. Code trials:

   ```
   ChromeOptions  options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
   _driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
   ```

Could you please guide me resolve this ???

Comment: What does your login code look like?

Comment: It's as simple -

 public void LogIn()
        {

            ClearLoginFields();
            _userNameFieldElement.SendKeys(UserName);
            _passwordFieldElement.SendKeys(Password);
            _signInButtonElement.Submit();

        }